# How do I use Perl to send mail via a relay that only supports certificate based authentication

Tags: perl, email, authentication, certificate

I have been using [`Email::Sender`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email%3a%3aSender) with [`Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email%3a%3aSender%3a%3aTransport%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aTLS)  send email using a `STARTTLS` enabled relay. The relay has recently changed to using X.509 certificates for authentication. However I note that `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS` has no option to point to my certificate. Neither does `Net::SMTP::TLS` on which `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS` is based.

Can someone suggest a solution? Another module perhaps that will allow me to authenticate using a certificate.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the dependency tree: `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS` ==> `Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained` ==> `IO::Socket::SSL` ==> `Net::SSLeay`

Both `IO::Socket::SSL` and `Net::SSLeay` supporting the X.509 client certificates. So `Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained` and `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS` should be enhanced to support client certificates. A proper way should update both modules to allow the `SSL_key|SSL_key_file` and `SSL_cert|SSL_cert_file` parameters.

Here is a quick dirty one -- you need to create modified `Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained` and keep it locally.

```
# modify the Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained; 
# built a private version which have client certificates
sub starttls {
    my $me = shift;
    $me->_command("STARTTLS");
    my ( $num, $txt ) = $me->_response();
    if ( not $num == 220 ) {
        croak "Invalid response for STARTTLS: $num $txt\n";
    }
    if (
        not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL(
            $me->{sock}, 
            SSL_version => "SSLv3 TLSv1", 
            ### private changes begin: append following two lines. 
            SSL_use_cert => 1,
            SSL_cert_file => "path_to/your/certificate_file.pem",
            SSL_key_file => "path_to/your/private_key_file.pem"
            ### private changes end:
        )
      )
    {
        croak "Couldn't start TLS: " . IO::Socket::SSL::errstr . "\n";
    }
    $me->hello();
}
```

Please leave the User and Password parameter as blank.

*Good luck!*

Comment: Thanks!! Thats really useful. Will keep this question updated to reflect the implementation

Answer (score 1):

for completeness sake, Net::SMTP can do this if IO::Socket::SSL is available (don't ask me since when, but I know it works with recent versions of both modules).

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMTP;

my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(
    Host    => 'host.domain.tld',
    Hello   => 'hi there',
    Port    => 587,
    Timeout => 5,
    Debug   => 4,
);

$smtp->starttls(
    SSL_cert_file   => "/path/to/crt",
    SSL_key_file    => "/path/to/key",
);

$smtp->mail("user\+perl\@domain\.nl\n");
$smtp->to("user\@otherdomain\.tld\n");
$smtp->data;
$smtp->datasend("From: Your Name <user\@domain.tld>\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: Recipient <user\@otherdomain.tld>\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: certificate based relay testing\n");
$smtp->datasend("MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
$smtp->datasend("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n");
$smtp->datasend("X-Mailer: Net::SMTP IO::Socket::SSL\n");
$smtp->datasend( "X-mydate: " . localtime() . "\n" );
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("testing again\n");
$smtp->dataend;
$smtp->quit;
```

The host must exactly match the subject in the certificate, or it will not validate.

I assume your system trusts the certificate authority of the relay server, otherwise you need to fix that too.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info